# Create a pandas DataFrame of specified shape containing the same dict in every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to create a `pandas.DataFrame` which contains the same `dict` in every row:

input:

```
length = 5
a = {'this':1, 'is':2, 'an':3 'example':4}
```

output:

```
                                             0
0  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
1  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
2  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
3  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
4  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
```

How could I do this properly?

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried anything? Please see [ask] [help/on-topic].

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame([[a]] * length)`` ?

Comment: The issue obviously is that I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method -

```
import pandas as pd

length = 5
a = {'this':1, 'is':2, 'an':3, 'example':4}

out = pd.DataFrame({0:[a] * length})
print(out)
```

```
                                             0
0  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
1  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
2  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
3  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
4  {'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'an': 3, 'example': 4}
```